# How to achieve this svg animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, svg

world. I am a noob coder, was hoping to get my question answered here for the first time!

I am trying to get something like [these](https://ivomynttinen.com/) (the three animations right under the banner) svg animations for my own website.

```css
/* CSS */

svg {
      max-width: 95%;
      max-height: 95%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin: auto;
    }
```

```html
    /* HTML */ 

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="212px"
      height="154px" viewBox="0 0 212 154" style="enable-background:new 0 0 212 154;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
     .st0{fill:#999999;}
     .st1{fill:none;stroke:#999999;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    </style>
    <defs>
    </defs>
    <g>
     <path class="st0" d="M211,1v152H1V1H211 M212,0H0v154h212V0L212,0z"/>
    </g>
    <line class="st1" x1="62.5" y1="1" x2="62.5" y2="153"/>
    <polyline class="st1" points="1,97.65 14.31,97.65 62,97.65 "/>
    <line class="st1" x1="14.39" y1="153" x2="14.39" y2="98"/>
    <line class="st1" x1="62.1" y1="125.82" x2="14.9" y2="125.82"/>
    </svg>
```

I've made the svg via illustrator, and then exported the code into my coding program of choice, however I am unsure how to actually animate the lines so that it starts at one point and traces to another in a different color, in a variety of directions.

Hopefully i'm making sense here, any help would be awesome. Let me know if you have any solutions or resources that can help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this article for more information on how to animate SVG lines: https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

Here is an example using your SVG shape:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="212px"
        height="154px" viewBox="0 0 212 154" style="enable-background:new 0 0 212 154;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
        .st0{fill:#999999;}
        .st1{fill:none;stroke:#999999;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    </style>
    <defs>
    </defs>
    <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M211,1v152H1V1H211 M212,0H0v154h212V0L212,0z"/>
    </g>
    <line  class="st1" x1="62.5" y1="1" x2="62.5" y2="153"/>
    <polyline  class="st1" points="1,97.65 14.31,97.65 62,97.65 "/>
    <line class="st1" x1="14.39" y1="153" x2="14.39" y2="98"/>
    <line class="st1" x1="62.1" y1="125.82" x2="14.9" y2="125.82"/>
</svg>

svg {
    max-width: 95%;
    max-height: 95%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
svg .st0{
stroke:#4444ff;
stroke-width:2;
stroke-dasharray: 1000;
stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes dash {
to {
stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/yLLLeXJ?editors=1100

Comment: I think I've made some progress, what I've done was just create another svg that'll be my animation, I just need to figure out now how to place it directly ontop of my first svg, and get it to animate from beginning to end

https://codepen.io/DavidPicarazzi/project/editor/XJEVag

Comment: You can merge the two shapes together by placing the parts from the second shape into the first. You can take a look at my updated codepen here: https://codepen.io/kostasx/pen/yLLLeXJ?editors=1100

Comment: are the blue lines appearing from the original animation just self drawn svgs or are they actual lines created in html and styled in css to move a certain way?

Comment: Everything is SVG. @DavidPicarazzi.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar project where animations posed a challenge. I initially tried out using a video, then a GIF, but finally ended up using SVG.

Although, there isn't a straight solution like a method to call because each animation is unique, here are options that can help you get started.

1. SVG animation libraries like [GreenSock](https://greensock.com/) or [SnapSVG](http://snapsvg.io/)
2. Using [Airbnb Lottie](https://airbnb.design/lottie/) - you can design using Adobe Illustrator and Lottie will output as JSON

I ended up using Lotties, as the JSON structure was a handy approach.

Comment: Lotties looks super helpful. I thought you could only use After Effects with it? Is there a reason to put the actual code for the animation instead of just simply adding it as a video? Would the process for this go like: I create the animation in after effects, then use bodymovin to export it?

Comment: videos are messy, especially with the aspect ratios in play. Lottie might be the way to go